# How to execute multple web workers from a single method through parameter in typescript

Tags: typescript, web, background-process, web-worker

I have the following code block for executing web worker. The following method is working fine.

```
async executeWorker() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if (typeof Worker !== 'undefined') {
        const worker = new Worker(new URL('../workers/app.some.worker', import.meta.url));
        
        worker.onmessage = ({ data }) => {
           receiving values...
          }
          worker.terminate();
          resolve(true);
        };
        worker.postMessage(passing values...);
      } else {
        reject(false);
      }
    });
  }
```

But as per my requirement, I need to execute multiple web workers which are placed into another folder in the app. So, I modified the above method by adding parameter and passing the parameter in the worker url and calling from a for-each loop. But the method throws an error "**Failed to construct 'worker': Script at 'file:///<valid worker file path>)' cannot be accessed from origin <valid url>**".

```
async executeWorker(workerName: string) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if (typeof Worker !== 'undefined') {
        const worker = new Worker(new URL('../workers/app.' + workerName + '.worker', import.meta.url));
        
        worker.onmessage = ({ data }) => {
           receiving values...
          }
          worker.terminate();
          resolve(true);
        };
        worker.postMessage(passing values...);
      } else {
        reject(false);
      }
    });
  }
```

So, my question is how to execute multple web workers from a single method through parameter like above.

Comment: I can't see where you did a modification or where the `forEach` loop in your code is

Comment: I have not added forEach part here. I have modified the method executeWorker() by adding parameter and passing the parameter in the worker url.